# Data labels cutting off in jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm working with jqplot, and am seeing some odd series label behavior.
If the value is too large, the labels don't show. I can't find a setting that preserves canvas area for the labels. Any thoughts?

[example fiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/abenrob/nDcPB/11/

```
$(document).ready(function(){          
    optionsObj = {
        grid: {
            background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)",
            drawBorder: false,
            shadow: false
        }, 
        seriesColors: ["#6699FF"],
        seriesDefaults:{
            shadow:false, 
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection: 'horizontal',
                barWidth:15,
                barMargin: 5
            }
        }, 
        series:[
            {pointLabels:{
                show: true
            }}],
        axesDefaults: {
            rendererOptions: {
            drawBaseline: false
            }
        },
        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions:{
                    showGridline:false, 
                    markSize:0
                }
            },
            xaxis:{
                tickOptions:{
                    show: false,
                    showGridline:false, 
                    markSize:0
                }
            }
        }
    };
    // labels not shown
    plot = $.jqplot('chart1', [[[507740000000,'Budget'],[496740000000,'Forecast'],[506740000000,'Expended']]], optionsObj)
    // labels shown
    plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [[[50774000,'Budget'],[49674000,'Forecast'],[50674000,'Expended']]], optionsObj)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like jqPlot will render them if there's not enough space to the right of your bars.  You can use the xaxis pad option to provide more space but I also had to throw a `min: 0` in there to get the auto-scaling to behave a little saner:

```
...
      xaxis:{
            tickOptions:{
                show: false,
                showGridline:false, 
                markSize:0
            },
           min: 0,
           pad:1.8
        }
...
```

[image]

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nDcPB/13/).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help. I ended up formatting to #K,#M etc, but this is much better.